# not updating datasource

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagridview, datasource, updating

I seem to be having some trouble getting my `DataGridView` to update the `DataSource`. I currently have a the `DataSource` set to a `Linq` query as you ca see in the code below.

```
With dgvTrophies
    ' Automatically generate the DataGridView columns.
    .AutoGenerateColumns = True

    ' Set up the data source.
    .DataSource = From t In db.Trophies _
                      Where t.ShootId = shootIdProp _
                      Select New With {.Trophy = t.TrophyName, t.IDNo, t.Name, t.Score, .Sngls = t.SnglsClass.ToString, .Hcp = t.HcpYardage, .Dbls = t.DblsClass.ToString, .Category = t.Category.ToString, t.Printed}

    ' Automatically resize the visible rows.
    .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders

    ' Set the DataGridView control's border.
    .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle

    ' Set the Editing mode for User
    .EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystroke

    ' Hides the Row Headers
    .RowHeadersVisible = False
End With
```

When editing the cell it does not update the database, it was my understanding that a `DataGridView` will update the database automatically with what you have entered.

I have done lots of looking around on the internet and haven't found anything. If someone can either provide me a solution to my problem or point me in the correct direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: no, you can't update the data with `DataGridView.DataSource = Linq` only to Database. you must create a method, something like `update method` for updating your data to database using linq or else.

Comment: I think it should be possible to use Linq and a BindingSource. Then you just set the bindingsource to be the datasource to the datagridview. And remember to do bindingsource.ResetBindings(true) when you do an update. Correct me if I am wrong now people :)

Comment: That may work, but for my solution, I ended up taking the entire entity, `t`, in my Linq statement and setting that to the `datasource`, hiding un-needed columns. Also performing a `db.SubmitChanges()` upon leaving edit mode correctly updated the database. Thanks for the help guys!